# Passing Pointer to Function Anomaly

Tags: c, function, pointers, pass-by-value

Why would the output of the below program be `0x0`?

```
BYTE n_buffer[4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4};

int GetElement(BYTE *pElement, DWORD dwIndex)
{
    pElement = &n_buffer[dwIndex];
    return SUCCESS;
}

int main()
{
    BYTE *res2 = NULL;
    GetElement(res2, 3);
    printf("0x%X\n", res2);
}
```

Comment: what is `BYTE`? `char`? `char *`?

Comment: unsigned char basically.

Comment: `func(x)` can never change `x`. C uses pass-by-value which means the function receives a copy of the argument.  (Imagine what would happen to `func(5)` if this was not true...)

Answer (score 3):

In your `GetElement()` function, `res2` has been passed using pass-by-value. `pElement` is local to `GetElement()` function.

Any changes to `*pElement` will be reflected back in `main()`, changes to  `pElement` itself won't.

So, after returning from `GetElement()` function, `res2` in `main()` will still be NULL.

Note: if you want to change `res2` from `GetElement()` function, you need to pass a pointer to `res2` as argument.

Answer (score 3):

You dont return any pointers, my guess is that you want to pass the address of the pointer and assign its value

```
int GetElement(BYTE **pElement, DWORD dwIndex)
{
 *pElement = &n_buffer[dwIndex];
 return SUCCESS;
}
```

Try to draw the the pointers and where they point and read a little bit more about pointers.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
int GetElement(BYTE **pElement, DWORD dwIndex)
{
    *pElement = &n_buffer[dwIndex];
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

and the main

```
int main()
{
    BYTE *res2 = NULL;
    GetElement(&res2, 3);
    printf("0x%X\n", res2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Function parameters are local variables of the function. After exiting the function they are destroyed.

You may imagine function GetElement

```
int GetElement(BYTE *pElement, DWORD dwIndex)
{
    pElement = &n_buffer[dwIndex];
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

and its call

```
BYTE *res2 = NULL;
GetElement(res2, 3);
```

the following way

```
int GetElement()
{
    BYTE *pElement = res2, 
    DWORD dwIndex = 3;

    pElement = &n_buffer[dwIndex];
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Thus because `pElement` has a copy of the value of `res2` `res2` itself will not be changed.

You should define the function  and call it the following way

```
int GetElement(BYTE **pElement, DWORD dwIndex)
{
    *pElement = &n_buffer[dwIndex];
    return SUCCESS;
}

// ...

BYTE *res2 = NULL;
GetElement( &res2, 3 );
```

The other approach is to define the function like

```
BYTE * GetElement( DWORD dwIndex)
{
    return (dwIndex < 4 ? &n_buffer[dwIndex] : NULL );
}

// ...

BYTE *res2 = NULL;
res2 = GetElement( 3 );
```